# UiTextField doesn't rotate wehn I rotate the iPad

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, uitextfield, orientation

I have a CCLayer with a UITextfield.

```
textfield = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(posY, posX, 200, 45)];
[textfield setDelegate:self];
textfield.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(textfield.transform, M_PI * (-90.0 / 180.0));
```

Everything works fine. But when I rotate the iPad the whole screen changes the orientation but NOT the inputfield. (Only landscape-mode is activated). How can I make the inputfield rotate, too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open GameConfig.h and set autorotation type to use the UIViewController (RootViewController).